# Unable to get date xAxis working with unix timestamp

Tags: anychart

I am having some trouble understanding the Anychart axis documentation.

Using this example https://jsfiddle.net/gvb29tc2/2/ i have some data points i want to plot using the unix date stamp for x-axis.

```
[
1497786600,                                       // <- ID
'Sun Jun 18 2017 19:53:35 GMT+0800 (SGT)',        // <- date
1497786815630,                                    // <- unix date
...
]
```

I select it using `x: new Date([2]),` but i cant get it to display. Just outputs a single vertical line. Also, i wanted the major tick on 5min and minor on 2min. Can't get that working either.

Since all i am trying is a simple line chart, i think i'm missing something stupid. Can someone explain where i'm going wrong please ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use any functions in mapping settings.
Right way is

```
x:[2]
```

After that you can work with mapped value as timestamp
https://jsfiddle.net/gvb29tc2/4/